Why declaration of friend to nested templates member fuction work in class, but not in template
I have this code, successfully compiled with g++ 13.3.0.
template<typename T1>
class H1 
{
    template<typename T2>
    class H2 {
        void Hh(int) {}
    };
};

// template<typename T3> // not compiling 
class H3 
{
    template<typename T1>
    template<typename T2>
    friend void H1<T1>::H2<T2>::Hh(int); // The issue row 253

};

If uncomment "template<typename T3>" g++ return:
g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test1.d" -MT"src/Test1.o" -o "src/Test1.o" "../src/Test1.cpp"
../src/Test1.cpp:253:27: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  253 |     friend void H1<T1>::H2<T2>::Hh(int);
      |                           ^

What should change in friend definition?

Clang doesn't even support non-template case Demo fallback to more permissive friendship as I understand.

template helps clang void H1<T1>::template H2<T2>::Hh(int), turning error into warning (as unsupported) Demo

While you can declare a template or a member of a dependent type a friend ([temp.friend]/4–5), that doesn’t extend to arbitrarily complicated friend declarations in a template-declaration.  Note that H1<T1>::H2<T2>::Hh(int) is not itself a function template.
GCC is evidently checking more carefully when in a template, probably because it has to store a representation of the friend declaration for longer.
